# Behavior of EntityManager when persisting Entities with/without GeneratedValue ids that are detached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like someone to answer with the behavior of a javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist() for the following different cases:

(please, if some of these cases reduce to one same case, also say so; and if some of the cases (i.e.: case c) that I have implicitly reduced to only one case should be separated because of different behaviors, please also say so)

The object that I am persisting:

a) Is detached and has already a @GeneratedValue @Id field already set, and there exists in the persistence context / database an entity with that same id.

b) Is detached and has already a @GeneratedValue @Id field already set, but there does not exist in the persistence context / database an entity with that same id.

c) Is detached, but its @GeneratedValue @Id field is not yet set.

d) Is detached, but its primary key is not auto-generated, and is already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for all the cases:

a) It will throw an EntityExistsException.

b) It will ignore the value set and it will set its own generated value when the entity is flushed to the database.

c) Same as b.

d) It will persist only if no object in the PersistenceContext has the same primary key, otherwise, it will throw an EntityExistsException as in a.